# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'api_key' in temp-mail python

Tags: python

I Get This Error. And I can't see any pieces of information in the readme

```
tm = TempMail()
TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'api_key'
```

Please, someone, tell the problem and give a solution.

Comment: you are missing the positional argument :/, you need to provide api_key when creating a class object

Answer (score 0):

Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will help make your questions more clear in the future.

I believe you are using [tempmail2](https://github.com/CITGuru/tempmail).
In that case, the README states:

> Before you can use this, you need to get api key from https://market.mashape.com/Privatix/temp-mail.

Once you get an API key from that website, you can run `tm = TempMail(API_KEY_HERE)` and your problem should be solved.